# Comparing elements between groups in R

Tags: r, comparison

I have a data frame arranged as below:

```
DEPUTIES     CHAMBER       (...)    
1 2496       1       
2 2577       1       
3 2577       2       
4 2577       3        
5 2577       4        
6 2578       2     
(...)
```

I have 2322 different deputies and 4 chambers, but some deputies appear in more than one chamber. What I want to do is to create a variable that indicates whether a deputy was in the previous chamber ("reelection") or not (the first chamber will be discarded later). I think it is probably simple, but could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
df <- df[order(df$DEPUTIES,df$CHAMBER),]
df$r <- unlist(aggregate(CHAMBER~DEPUTIES,df,function(x)c(NA,diff(x)))$CHAMBER)
df
#   DEPUTIES CHAMBER  r
# 1     2496       1 NA
# 2     2577       1 NA
# 3     2577       2  1
# 4     2577       3  1
# 5     2577       4  1
# 6     2578       2 NA
```

This orders the df by deputies and chamber (already ordered that way it seems, but to be sure...). Then, using `aggregate(...)`, for each deputy calculate the difference between the current chamber number and the previous. If this is >0, they went from, e.g ,chamber 1 to chamber 2. Not sure what to do if someone starts in a chamber > 1 but never advances??